# Extending a reduction relation

Tags: racket, redex

While taking a look at PLT redex, I wanted to play with simplification rules; so  I defined this minimal language for booleans:

```
(define-language B0
  (b T F (not b)))
```

I wanted to simplify a chain of `(not (not ...))` so I extended the language to deal with contexts and defined a reduction relation to simplify the `not`:

```
(define-extended-language B1 B0
  (C (not C) hole)
  (BV T F))

(define red0
  (reduction-relation
   B1
   (--> (in-hole C (not T)) (in-hole C F))
   (--> (in-hole C (not F)) (in-hole C T))))
```

Now I wanted to extend my language to boolean equations and to allow `not`-simplification at each side of the equation, so I defined:

```
(define-extended-language B2 B1
  (E (= C b) (= b C)))
```

hoping that:

```
(define red1
  (extend-reduction-relation red0 B2))
```

will do the thing.
But no: `red1` can reduce `(not (not (not F)))))` but not `(= (not T) F)))`

Am I doing something really silly here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `red1` is that it only contains the rules of `red0` which use the limited context `C`. To make it work as expected you could either add the old rules modified to use `E` or make somehow the final extended context have the name `C`. One not very tedious approach could be:

```
(define-language L)

(define R
  (reduction-relation L
    (--> (not T) F)
    (--> (not F) T)))

(define-language LB
  (b T F (not b))
  (C (compatible-closure-context b)))

(define RB (context-closure R LB C))

(define-extended-language LBE LB
  (e (= b b))
  (C .... (compatible-closure-context e #:wrt b)))

(define RBE (extend-reduction-relation RB LBE))
```

Note that this doesn't work in some older versions.

Two sources of useful information are [this tutorial](https://williamjbowman.com/doc/experimenting-with-redex/) and of course [the redex reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/redex/The_Redex_Reference.html).